# Problem Opening a Project with 2021.3.35f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been using Unity version 2019.4.1f1 for the last 4 years, and I decided to switch to 2021.3.35f1.

I deleted my older version and downloaded 2021.3.35f1 through the Unity Hub.

Once I had it downloaded, I tried to make a new project with it, but it told me the project could not be opened.

The log files show that there might be an issue with Unity Cloud, but I have no idea what it means.

How do I fix this?

[image: Image Of log File]

I can't read log so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Have you tried refresh license?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of logs or error messages. Paste the relevant text in your question so it can be found using search.

Comment: Hi! I fixed the error by updating my 3d Core!

Answer (score 0):

Update your 3D Core in Unity Hub!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).